# Making an exception in EmailField validation in django

Tags: django, validation, django-forms, emailfield

I have model called `EmailHistory` with one of the fields that look like this:

```
from_email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="From:")
```

I created a ModelForm and want to validate for email addresses unless it's set to "Anonymous". I tried the following, to no avail.

```
class EmailForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmailHistory
        exclude = ('to_email')

    to_emails = forms.CharField()

    def clean_from_email(self):

        from_email = self.cleaned_data['from_email']
        if from_email == "Anonymous":
            return from_email
        else:
            return super(EmailForm, self).clean_from_email();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that, as [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/forms/validation/) explains, the `clean` method of the underlying form field - which in turn runs the validators - is run before the specific `clean_form_field` method in the form itself. You'll probably want to use a normal CharField in your form, and add the email validation into the clean method yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to work without redefining `from_email`. So, I redefined it and then did an email validation using `django.core.validators.validate_email`:

```
class EmailForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmailHistory
        exclude = ('to_email')

    to_emails = forms.CharField()
    from_email = forms.CharField(required=True)

    def clean_from_email(self):
        from_email = self.cleaned_data['from_email']
        if from_email == "Anonymous":
            from_email = "myemail@example.com"

        validate_email(from_email)

        return from_email
```